# declare a variable ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, declare

In the example given at

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I got confused by variable "comment".

The original version is

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

In this version, I can understand "comment" is from |comment|

Then, in section 7, this part is changed into

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

In the app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb
the code is

```
<p>
  <strong>Commenter:</strong>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>
```

Then I got confused. Where is "comment" declared?

Is there a tutorial introducing how variables declared in ruby on rails?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rendering-collections-in-rails) should clear it up. The core of it is that

```
<% render @post.comments %>
```

will do the same thing as

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: comment } %>
<% end %>
```

Your variable `comment` inside the partial template is declared by `render`, triggered by the `locals` hash. The article further explains the magic of how you get the latter from the former.

Comment: Thanks. The place I feel very confusing is where "comment" is. We have "comments". But I don't get the rule from "comments" to "comment".

Comment: If I have <% render @post.abcs %>, should I always expect "do |abc|" ?

Comment: By the way, could you please let me know the link of explanation of this magic? I can't find it?

Comment: @user3440433, http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rendering-collections-in-rails is the link, are you not getting it?

Comment: Yes, `render @post.abcs` would define an `abc` local in your partial template.

Comment: @rubyprince, Thanks. But I am still confused. The question is about locals: { comment: comment }. Why not locals: { commentABC: comment } or locals: { comment123: comment }. I don't understand which part decides the title is comment instead of commentABC or comment123.

Comment: @Amadan, Thanks. What if render @post.abc? Will it define ab local in my partial template? Is there an official rule here?

Comment: Remember that `@post.comments` is defined by your association, most likely `has_many :comments` in the `Post` model. The model that is associated is, by default, obtained by [`String#singularize`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/String/singularize). The variable name will be the `downcase` variant of that. `@post.abc` is either not a collection, or if is then it was declared with a `class_name` modifier, and will therefore use the word derived from that class name (I think; haven't tested or looked it up, because in my normal work I would never name a `has_many` association with a singular).

Comment: Also, `singularize` is smart enough to know that `Account.people` has `Person` objects. It does not simply cut off the last character, but has a fairly nice model of English plurals.